# Suggestions needed

Tags: c++, pointers

I have spent a month on grasping the basics of C++. Pointers, vectors, etc.. Everywhere I read the theory and I am like, i know this. I really want to solve pointer problems so that I know I"ll be able to apply the concept. Can anyone recommend a book or pointer questionnares (Cause I feel they are the toughest to implement) I can go through?

Thanks.

Comment: You should just try to do something yourself and ask a more specific question when you run into problems.

Comment: Why don't you just start programming for real? You'll come across pointers before long, unless you're going for modern C++ idioms. Or start answering questions on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Implement a (doubly or circular) linked list. Make sure it's memory efficient and cleans up after itself. While you're at it, implement some algorithms for it, such as tortoise-and-hare.

Comment: I thought of this this morning and actually came back to say this exact thing.